# ABCpdf10 changes my font size (reduce size)

Tags: c#, abcpdf

When generating pdf from an html and css it generates the pdf with the different size to the one that I have in css, to what is this symptom due?

[image]

In css I have 9pt and 8pt but in pdf it gives me 7pt and 6.5pt

Answer (score 0):

This could depend on which engine you are using to render the pdf, IE / Geko for v10

You can set the render type when generating make sure the following are set for the best results.

```
    theDoc.HtmlOptions.Media = MediaType.Screen;
    theDoc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;
```

It should be noted that v10 is 2 versions behind the current one and it might help to upgrade.